# How do we deserialize value/key from Struct data?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

We use `io.confluent.connect.sftp.SftpCsvSourceConnector` to read csv file from sftp location and push the message into kafka.... but the message in kafka topic dont come as a **csv** (string, separated comma), but the comme in specific key-value format **Struct** : ex Struct{branchBaseCurrCode=EUR, Country=CA} ...

I use Kafka-Streams.... how do I deserialize this ? what config should I use? what java object does it deserialize to? Can I deserialize this straight to my POJO knowing that I my attributes are exactly the same as the schema?

Can the `SftpCsvSourceConnector` writes directly the in `json` instead of `Struct` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your connector to use an appropriate `Converter`, such as Avro, Protobuf, etc. You can even use plain JSON if you want.

E.g.:

```json
"value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
```

See https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained